# How to convert Flash game to use BitmapData?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata, blit

Currently I have a Flash AS3 game that doesn't use any `BitmapData` techniques. However, due to performance reasons, I'd like to implement it.

I cannot find a single comprehensive tutorial for using `Bitmap` and `BitmapData` classes for a game.

Essentially I have a `World` class which acts as the game "world" container which holds all game objects (players, items, etc). Within `World` is the only `ENTER_FRAME` event which then ticks each object:

```
private function frameHandler(e:Event):void {

    if (!isPaused) {

        for (i = 0; i < characters.length; i ++) { 
            characters[i].tick();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < controllers.length; i ++) { 
            controllers[i].tick();
        }

        //Etc...

    }

}
```

How can I implement `BitmapData` into this system?

**EDIT**

Currently all of my world objects are using highly detailed vector graphics which cause performance to suffer when there are many on stage. This is why I'm turning to bitmaps.

Comment: `Bitmap`s don't differ from `MovieClip`s in terms of their ability to be displayed, but if the character's base is `MovieClip` and not `Sprite`, you'll have to mimic `gotoAndStop()` behavior of MCs with your bitmap-based characters. I cannot derive the actual question of what is your target condition. Do you plan to use blitting everywhere, or just shift MCs for bitmaps, or do you want to change for bitmaps because you *think* they will be faster? There is a lot to overcome should you shift to bitmaps from vector graphics of any kind.

Comment: @Vesper All of my world objects are either `MovieClip`s or `Sprite`s. I am turning to using bitmaps because performance suffers when there are multiple characters (vector graphics). I've read that it is common for games to use one `BitmapData` object and just draw the game scene there somehow.

Comment: This technique is called "blitting". There are some blitting tutorials out there, but for actual performance gain, you should not do direct `draw()` of everything onto main bitmap, the primary drawing function should be `copyPixels()` which requires a bitmapdata be aligned with main bitmap in terms of rotation (otherwise you'll be drawing a character that's facing wrong way), it only accepts even pixel coordinates, and you will have to maintain the display list yourself instead of letting Flash do this.

Comment: All this might be too hard to accommodate with existing graphics, say if a character has a rotating part, you need to separately blit its base and its rotating part, which should have a set of `BitmapData`s containing images of that rotating part in all rotation positions that will ever be used in your game. If that rotation is full circle, an approximation can be used, by building say 36 of these containing images rotated in a step of 10 degrees. This quickly adds up if there are many different rotating objects, although some of these can use the same set of bitmaps to be drawn.

Comment: You can, on the other hand, have entire character drawn as a bitmap in all positions available for display, say a complex attack animation can be drawn frame by frame and re-used whenever your in-game character performs the attack. This is called sprite animation, you can even render that animation at runtime by doing a set of `draw` calls prior to letting the user play (aka "Loading animation"). These can also be reused, and are best kept static, so that when a character is to be drawn, an existing `BitmapData` is used to display the character.

Comment: @Vesper Thanks for the info. So there is no way for me to easily use `BitmapData` instead? Since the drop in performance is only due to the detailed vector graphics, I was hoping for some way to draw everything in the world to the bitmap and keeping the world hidden (`visible = false`).

Comment: "Easily"? No. You will need a lot of `BitmapData`s to accomplish a complete transfer to rasterized graphics. And as I've said, you can still use vector graphics to draw characters on rasters, but the more you call `draw()` per frame, the more laggy will be the transition.